# Comparing file contents and table contents - Encoding issues?

Tags: c#, encoding, datatable, string-comparison

I read the contents of a file into a datatable using the following method:

```
public static DataTable GetFileContents(string filePath, IEnumerable<string> columnNames)
        {
            using (var conn = new StreamReader(filePath,Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                string strLine;
                var dt = new DataTable();
                var columnCount = 0;
                const char delimiter = '\t';
                foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(string));
                    columnCount++;
                }
                while ((strLine = conn.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var columnData = strLine.Split(delimiter);
                    var j = 0;
                    var columns = new string[columnCount];
                    while (j < columnCount)
                    {
                        columns[j] = columnData[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(columns);
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

and then I retrieve the contents of my table into a List and then compare the value in the list to the values in the datatable and the main comparison is as follows:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Single(x=>x.ItemArray[0].ToString().Equals(tableRow[0].ToString()))
```

I have even tried the following:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Single(
                                x => Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(x.ItemArray[0].ToString()).SequenceEqual(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tableRow[0].ToString())));
```

Although I see the values match exactly but still the above Linq query fails with No Result Found. Any idea what is the reason?

The file is in Unicode format.

Sample Code :

```
var tableList = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlString).List<object>();
foreach (var row in tableList)
{
var tableRow= (IList)row;
//my comparison code as mentioned above
//other code
}
```

byte array of value 1233 retrieved from file:
[image: byte array of 1233 from file]

byte array of 1233 from db:
[image: byte array of 1233 from db]

Comment: The `Single` call you've given wouldn't compile - the version with a parameter takes a delegate, not a `bool`. It therefore isn't the code you're running, which makes it hard to say what's wrong...

Comment: And what is `tableRow`? It would be really helpful if you could convert this into a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet its basically a `collection(list)` which contains all the column values in a row.. i have added a short code to show how it is retrieved,FYI im using Nhibernate..

Comment: Well LINQ to Objects definitely *does* work, so I'm confident that *that's* not the problem. But without knowing what `tableRow[0]` is, or what's in your text file, it's pretty hard to work out what the problem is. Again, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help.

Comment: @JonSkeet creating the sample prog will take smtime in the mean time I have added the screenshot of the byte array of the strings retrieved from the file and db.. both values are the same i.e 1233 and I used Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() method to get the bytearray. Not sure what the initial 255 254 represents.. any idea?

Comment: That's a byte order mark, used to identify the byte ordering of a file. If that's being read as part of the first string, no wonder the comparison is failing.

Comment: what do you think is the prob? is it in how I am reading the file or how the file is being written into.. FYI, the file is a merge of output of database dumps using the BCP utility..

Comment: It's how you're reading the file - I'd actually have *expected* it to be automatically removed by `StreamReader`, but you might want to try using `File.ReadAllLines` (or `File.ReadLines` if you're using .NET 4) and see whether that sorts it for you.

Comment: both of them did not help, they continue to return the byte order mark.. FYI, I used the `CopyTo` method to merge the files..

Comment: Okay, you could always use `TrimStart` to trim off the BOM, if absolutely necessary...